# How can I get selected div on scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, cursor

I have a div contains lots of cells with random height.
The aim is : "the user stop the scroll to choose a cell, all cells can be chosen".
A cell is selected/chosen by a cursor at the left top corner.
The cursor change of cell when user scroll the div.
I have made a demo, but the problem is when user is at the bottom, the N last cells can't be selected by cursor.
How can I do this please ?

Thank you for help :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 + 1) + 20);
    $('.content').append('<div id="' + i + '" class="cell" style="height:' + h + 'px;"></div>');
  }
  
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var id = current();
    $('.cursor').css('top', $('#' + id).position().top + 'px')
  });
});

function current() {
  $('.cell').each(function() {
    if ($(this).position().top > $(document).scrollTop()) {
      id = $(this).attr('id');
      return false;
    }
  });
  return id;
}
```

```css
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.cursor {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/lokomass/pen/OJyXXwV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your event is based on scroll and at the end when the scroll stops it cannot decide which element to give cursor on so just add the following css in your code to increase the space at the bottom of the content to keep on scrolling till the last element.

```
.content {
  margin-bottom : 130px;
}
```

Or just make the last parameter as 65.

```
 var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 + 1) + 65);
```

**Note:** It atleat require 65 to get to the last one.

Comment: I can't change margin/padding, the div content is 100% height of the screen

Comment: do you have another idea please ? I think we need jquery

Comment: Ok i got another solution check out my answer i've edited it.

Comment: This is not a good solution For me. For thé exemple height are randomed but in my real form there is 3/4 cells at the bottom...

Comment: The only issue I see, its to calculate if scroll ls in the last part of div, and do reverse to sélect the first cell from the bottom. But the problem is the same, not a the bottom, juste above

Comment: ok by me these were the only options in your code that can bring the cange as desired sorry.

Comment: Because the scroll stops at the end and the position of the last two boxes can't be taken into consideration unitl and unless you add a margin at the bottom.

Comment: Do you have an idea or exemple to do this, i dont see how i can do

Comment: Another idea. I look all height of div and create an array. From 0px to 100px, its the id1, from 100 to 150, its id2... etc

Comment: Ok try it.Hope this helps you.